# Trailing backslash characters in the source

Tags: python

For a line in a given source(`f`),

```
0x223f01 X 32 fhsjskk, \
```

below code still picks this line and print it.

```
for line in f:
            line.rstrip('\n') # every line has \n            
            if not line.endswith('\\'):
                print(line)
```

---

In this scenario, one cannot avoid trailing backslash from the source.

How to detect trailing backslash characters?

Comment: @AdamSmith I need trailing backslash to detect before removing it... `line.strip()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rstrip()` returns the stripped string, it does not change the string itself. try:

```
line = line.rstrip('\n')
```

See: [`string.rstrip()` Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rstrip)

Comment: Does `line=line.strip()` remove `\n`?

Comment: Yes! In fact, it's most likely better to use `strip` with no arguments as it will remove all whitespace.

Comment: And as @AdamSmith suggests, _documentation is your friend._ ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `rstrip` function does not modify the original string, you need to change that line to `line = line.rstrip('\n')`